# Selenium extracting get attribute href extracting incomplete links

Tags: python, selenium

I'm extracting links from this [site](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attractions-g147288-Activities-c42-Dominican_Republic.html#TtD) for all categories. The code for extracting link and handling pagination is below:

```
  def parse_data(self,browser):
    b = open('link_list.csv', 'a')
    a = csv.writer(b, lineterminator='\n')
    try:
        vacations = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('property_title')
        for v in vacations:
            vacation_link = v.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
            a.writerow([vacation_link])

        self.pagination(browser)
    except:
        pass

   def pagination(self,browser):

      try:
        span = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.paging.pageDisplay')
        spantext = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.paging.pageDisplay').text
        #browser.execute_script('$('+str(span)+').next()')
        span.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::a[1]')
        span.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::a[1]').click()
        self.parse_data(browser)
      except:
        pass
```

Now as i run the code, some of the links are merged as:

```
http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g811253-d1633107-Reviews-Tauro_Tours-Santa_Barbara_de_Samana_Samana_Province_Dominican_http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g147290-d2512805-Reviews-Wise_Mountain_Retreat-Puerto_Plata_Puerto_Plata_Province_Dominican_Republic.html`
http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g259440-d7263743-Reviewshttp://www.tripadvisor.ca/Attraction_Review-g147288-d2292268-Reviews-Bahia_de_las_Aguilas-Dominican_Republic.html
```

Some of the links are corrupted as:

```
Paraiso-Cabrera_Maria_Trinidad_Sanchez_Province_Dominican_Republic.html
```

Comment: I see `span = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.paging.pageDisplay')` should be `span = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.paging pageDisplay')`

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) that is linked in the Help Center.